# Dynamic stylesheet linking using angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

This question is more for understanding how Angular $compile works.

Lets take the scenario where I want to change CSS stylesheet dynamically in my `<head>` section of view.

This is what I do in the controller:

```
$scope.theme = '<link rel="stylesheet" href="somepath.css" >'
$scope.$watch("theme", function(newTheme, oldTheme){
    var head = angular.element($('head')[0]);
    head.append($compile($scope.theme)($scope));
```

Now if somebody goes and changes like

`$scope.theme = '<link rel="stylesheet" href="somenewpath.css" >'`

then the page would reflect the new CSS style. But why do I need `$compile` here? Can't I just do `head.append($scope.theme);`

My fundamental question is then, how does the page update its style even though none of the style elements have any angular bindings?

Comment: in this case you not need use `$compile`. this need if you have string like `'<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{somepath}}.css" >'`

Comment: Okay. So my fundamental question remains. How does the css get applied on elements not in the model watched by angular?

Comment: You add link to style file in head, so all styles inside applying to all html elements on page